# Comparison test/ infinite series

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

[image: the picture]

Hello, 
So those are solutions for the same equation, which one is more likely correct and why?

Comment: Any real or complex series diverges if its general term does not go to zero.

Comment: Can you explain further

Comment: This is the first thing to know about seris, after the definition of the convergence.

Comment: Can you use the fact that, when $\frac{1}{n}$ is close to zero we have $ cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $ is close to 1 and $ sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $ is close to $\frac{1}{n}$?